# Error while creating chartjs in jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, chart.js

I am trying to create a bar chart using chartjs javascript framework in a jsp page. Chartjs takes input *data:[ ]* values from json file. Here is my code of **jsp page**.

```html
<section id="main">
      <div class="container">
   
        <%
          String sentiment = (String)request.getAttribute("SENTIMENT_RESULT");
        
        %>
       
        
        <div id="result-container">
            <p id="result">
              <%= sentiment %>
 
             
            </p>
                <a href="getProduct" class="btn btn-outline-  secondary btn-lg btn-block">Back to the list</a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="graph-container">
         <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    
      </div>

    </section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

the code of the **app.js** is as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "graph_values.json",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
            var positive_percent = data.positive_percent;
            console.log(positive_percent);
            var negative_percent = data.negative_percent;
            console.log(negative_percent);

  

        var myChart = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
             // Global Options
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

        var analysisChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
            data:{
              labels:['Positive', 'Negative'],
              datasets:[{
                label:'Analysis',
                data:[
                  positive_percent,
                  negative_percent,
                ],
                //backgroundColor:'green',
                backgroundColor:[
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                  
  
                ],
                borderWidth:1,
                borderColor:'#777',
                hoverBorderWidth:3,
                hoverBorderColor:'#000'
              }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                  display:true,
                  text:'Analysis',
                  fontSize:25
                },
                legend:{
                  display:false,
                  position:'right',
                  labels:{
                    fontColor:'#000'
                  }
                },
                layout:{
                  padding:{
                    left:50,
                    right:0,
                    bottom:0,
                    top:0
                  }
                },
                tooltips:{
                  enabled:true
                }
              }
            });
  },
        
  error: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

And here is the **graph_values** json file from where I am trying to insert the values :

```
{"negative_percent":15.310099999999998,"positive_percent":84.6899}
```

I am getting this error in a firefox console :

```
 TypeError: t is undefined[Learn More]    util.js:45:11
   {"negative_percent":15.310099999999998,"positive_percent":84.6899}
    XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
    Location: http://localhost:8080/BeProject/graph_values.json
    Line Number 1, Column 1:
    graph_values.json:1:1
```

I am new to ajax and javascript. I don't know what went wrong in this.